# What are the advantages of blood's redness?

Tags: hematology, red-blood-cell

Although this page (http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evosite/evo101/IIIE5aNotadaptation.shtml) denounces the idea that blood's redness is not an adaptation, I remain inquisitive on the matter since no scientific research has been performed in studying its possible advantages.

Does anyone have any ideas on the advantages of having red blood?

Thank you for your time and effort

Comment: I don't think there is an advantage in blood being red. It is a byproduct of the heme being coordinated in the middle of the heme as the active center. [Hemolymph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemolymph) has a copper atom there and is more blue/green due to this fact.

Comment: I think your article explained it quite well. Blood is an adaptation. The color of blood is not; it's a coincidence.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your detailed reply, your chemical background has proved useful here.

Comment: @anongoodnurse So what should I do with this question? Delete it?

Comment: Totally up to you. If you want a better answer, you can leave it and see what comes up?

Comment: I can make this into an answer if you want. It would be a rather short one, though.

Comment: @Chris I would be extremely grateful if you could do so please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why blood is red is rather simple: It is the iron atom in the middle of the heme, which plays the central part in binding oxygen. Depending on the oxidation state the blood looks either dark or light red. The structure is the following (taken from here):

[image]

That the color only depends on the coordinated metal atom is shown by another related molecule, the [hemocyanin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemocyanin), which is the oxygen carrying molecule in the [hemolymph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemolymph) of insects. It contains copper which is colorless in one oxidation state and blue-green in the other. The function is the same, the color is different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm a little confused - weren't there four Fe molecules?

Comment: This is true for the hemoglobin. This consists of four subunits. Each of these carries one heme with one iron atom. Together you have four hemes in the hemoglobin molecule.

Comment: Ah, I see - so your picture shows one heme and one iron atom

Comment: Yes, this is clearer this way.

Comment: @Chris did you mean blood is red rather than heart is red? I am changing it. Please revert if you feel it is wrong.

Comment: @CRags You are absolutely right. Thanks for finding this error.